# Do objects "store" information about their kinetic state, such as, e.g., momentum, and how?

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, information

Let's say a ball is rolling along a flat plane. How does the ball "know" in which direction to keep moving, and with what amount of force? Is this information stored in a particle in the ball?

To ask another way: there's two balls on a flat plane, one is rolling, one is stationary. Otherwise, the balls are identical. Are there any differences in the physical properties between these balls?

Comment: We don't know where the information is stored. I'm not even sure one could point anywhere and say, "The information is there". But I think we can all agree the information is definitely stored somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, is this the correct answer?

Comment: While we're at it, how does the ball know where it is, either?

Comment: I think it will help a lot if you take the above comment seriously.  Two balls, both stationary, are at different locations on the same tabletop.  Otherwise the balls are identical.  How does each ball know which position to occupy?  Is there any physical difference between the balls?  What would you consider to be an adequate answer to these questions?

Answer (score 3):

In physics, we do not talk about objects "knowing" what to do next or having desires or intentions. That belongs in the realm of prescientific, Aristotelian philosophy. Instead, today we talk about an initial condition of a physical system and the laws of physics which dictate how the physical system evolves with time. So you tell me the initial momentum and position of the ball and I will tell you what the ball will do next according to the laws of physics. There is no need for the ball to "know" anything.

Comment: My Q isn't asking whether we can make predictions about what a rolling ball will do in the future. I want to know if objects "store" momentum?

Comment: As I've written, that's simply not the right vocabulary when talking about physics. We can say that an object has momentum, but asking about how the object "knows" what to do next or where it "stores" momentum just isn't a meaningful question.

Comment: I'm not a scientist, so perhaps my vocab isn't quite right, but I know what I'm trying to ask. Let me pose the Q this way: There's two balls on a flat plane, one is rolling, one is stationary. Otherwise, the balls are identical. Are there any differences in the physical properties between these balls?

Comment: No, because whether an object is stationary or not depends on your frame of reference. In other words, motion is relative.

Comment: Ok.. what about if one of the balls was resting on the flat plane, but the other ball was accelerating. Any difference in the physical properties of the balls?

Comment: Well, one's accelerating and the other isn't : P

Comment: In _Physics_ these are the only sort of _Physical properties_ that matter

Comment: Marko, when we take a measurement, that information is recorded/transmitted by the measuring device. Did it not exist until it was measured? Did the measuring device create the information from nothing? See Wheeler's "it from bit". We don't know where its stored, and therefore the OP has no answer.